# ¿Como puedo verificar cuando cambia la secuencia números dentro de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

quisiera saber si alguno me podría ilustrar un poco  sobre que puedo hacer para comprobar lo siguiente dentro de un array de numero

- Completar años
- Si no hay 1 son todos del año actual
- Si hay 1 hay que chequear si hay un salto, si hay un salto son del año anterior

Ejemplo 1

> - 9 > 201909
> - 10 > 201910
> - 11 > 201911
> - 12 > 201912

Ejemplo 2

> - 1 > 201901
> - 2 > 201902
> - 3 > 201903
> - 11 > 201811
> - 12 > 201812

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías aclarar un poco más? Entiendo que deseas recorrer un array que contiene números. Hay unas condiciones sobre los números del array. Imagino que según las condiciones se debe construir un valor que es lo que tienes en tu ejemplo. La primera pregunta es, ¿los números en el array están relacionados con el número del mes? La siguiente pregunta es ¿Un salto significa que se pierde la continuidad de los números en el array? Otra pregunta, ¿El array puede tener más de 12 números? Como ves, hay muchas cosas que se tienen que aclarar. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿has intentado algo por tu cuenta? Si es así, te invito a editar tu pregunta y subir tu código.